# Conditions for two linearly independent solutions of the ODE representation of a diffusion to be global martingales

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $W_t$ be a Brownian Motion, $X_t$ and $M(t)$ be two stochastic processes:
$$X_t=adt+bdW_t$$ 
$$M(t)=e^{-\lambda t}\Phi(X_t)$$
where $\Phi$ is a deterministic function determined from the requirement that $M_t$ is a martingale and $X_t$ assumed to have values in the interval $[L,U]$.

By applying Ito's lemma and fixing the zero drift, we get
$$\lambda\Phi(X_t)=a\Phi^\prime (X_t)+\frac{b^2}{2}\Phi^{\prime\prime}(X_t)$$
which can be represented by the ODE  $\lambda\Phi(x)=a\Phi^\prime(x)+\frac{b^2}{2}\Phi^{\prime\prime}(x)$, which has two linearly independent solutions, $\phi_1(x)$ and $\phi_2(x)$, yielding two local martingales: $M_{1,2}(t)=e^{-\lambda t}\phi_{1,2}(X_t)$.

What else do I need in order to get that $M_{1,2}(t)$ are global martingales?
Suppose that $X_t$ does not have any singular point. Does this suffice to get that $M_{1,2}(t)$ are bounded?

Comment: If $X$ is bounded as you assume, then $M$, being a bounded local martingale, is a true martingale. But unless $b=0$, how can $X$ be bounded?

Comment: @AddSup that's why I was thinking of a condition on X. This is a hitting probability exercise where the two bounds are $L$ and $U$, respectively. Absence of singular point should imply that the function is smooth.